# What's the reason behind this design of rust?

Tags: rust, unsafe, ownership

Why does the below code not compile ?

I know that you can't leave any variable partially initialised but i do initialise in the next line, So is it that it's difficult for compiler to infer that ( though i don't really think that ) or is it for some other reason that i don't understand

This code is from [Too Many Linked Lists Book](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/first-push.html)

```rust
pub fn push(&mut self, elem: i32) {
    let new_node = Box::new(Node {
        elem: elem,
        next: self.head,
    });

    self.head = Link::More(new_node);
}
```

Comment: I think such self referencing wouldn't compile even if it was allowed to leave fields uninitialized

Comment: What was the error message?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text literally tells you why:

> In principle, this is something Rust could actually accept, but it won't (for various reasons -- the most serious being [exception safety](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/nomicon/exception-safety.html)).

And while in many cases rustc can be over-cautious, that's not the case here:

```rust
let node = Node { elem: elem, next: self.head };

let new_node = Box::new(new_node); // can panic, leaving `self` in an invalid state

self.head = Link::More(new_node);
```

Comment: Oh Okay now i get it , the Box<T> in itself could panic , Rust has so many fine things that i never noticed , again thank you